# Prove that if $f$ is a function such that $f'(x) > 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $f$ is a one to one function.

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-verification

Prove that if $f$ is a function such that $f'(x) > 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $f$ is a one to one function.

---

Set $f(x)$ to be some function such that $f'(x) > 0 \implies$ f(x) is increasing $\forall x$. Take two arbitrary and distinct values $a$ and $b$ with $a < b \implies f(a) < f(b) \implies \nexists a, b : f(a) = f(b) \therefore f$ is a one to one function.

---

Is this a sufficient proof?

Comment: Yes perfectly fine argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could use the Mean Value Theorem.

Suppose there exist $a<b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$.
Since $f'(x)>0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)$ is continuous and $f'(x)>0$ for $x\in [a,b]$.
Then by the MVT there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that
$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=0$ a contradiction.